# Does TOR client (Expert Bundle) work as an exit node by default?

Tags: exit-relays

I have downloaded TOR Expert Bundle standalone application. Does it work as an exit node by default?

**UPDATE.** Related: [Does running the Tor browser turn me into a (exit) relay?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10032/does-running-the-tor-browser-turn-me-into-a-exit-relay)

**Important.** My question is solely for TOR Expert Bundle, not for the TOR  Browser. It's crucial to have a separate question as official FAQ don't transparently state this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does running the Tor browser turn me into a (exit) relay?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10032/does-running-the-tor-browser-turn-me-into-a-exit-relay)

Answer (score 2):

By default it used not to, but nowdays - especially as IPv6 support was introduced - the manual about torrc and [ExitPolicy](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitPolicy) in precise - states it a bit unclear with default exit policies. So - now the answer is "YES". Use just 2 lines to secure it:

```
ExitPolicy reject *:*
ExitPolicy reject6 *:*
```